# How can I override or extend the method invoked at callback endpoint when using remote authentication scheme?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-oauth

I use Google OAuth to authenticate my users. It uses `RemoteAuthenticationHandler` which defines the `HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync` which is invoked at callback endpoint.

I want to override or extend this method to query database to select associated with google id my internal user id and set it in cookie, but I don't see any documented way to achieve this. How can I do it?

I was thinking about creating something like `ExternalAuthHandler<THandler, TOptions>` where THandler is `OAuthHandler<TOptions>` and `TOptions` is `OAuthOptions`. Then I could inherit from the `THandler` and invoke base class (e.g. `GoogleHandler` methods. But unfortunelly, I can't derive from generic parameter. It would be the best solution because I support multiple identity providers. Any idea how could I do some workaround?

This handler would look like this:

```
public class ExternalAuthenticationHandler<THandler, TOptions> : THandler 
// cannot inherit from generic parameter
    where TOptions : OAuthOptions, new()
    where THandler : OAuthHandler<TOptions>
{
}
```

Do u see any workaround or different approach?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the `.Events` property of the config.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking about way where I can use DI from constructor. Is that possible?

Comment: I've done something like `services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>, MyGoogleOptionsConfigurer>()` and then injected the services into the options configurer. Sorry I don't have a full solution and only a suggestion of how to do it.

Comment: I edited question and added my idea. Do u see any workaround?